# Lazarus TImage to Base64

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to encode a TImage picture to base64 for rest transmission, I've tried a couple ways and I can't seem to get it to encode as string. This is what I have now:

```
      imgstream := TStringStream.Create('');
      OutputStream := TStringStream.Create('');
      Encoder := TBase64EncodingStream.Create(OutputStream);
      try
        image1.Picture.SaveToStream(imgstream);
        Encoder.CopyFrom(imgstream, imgstream.Size);

        showmessage(OutputStream.DataString);
      finally
        imgstream.Free;
        Encoder.Free;
        OutputStream.Free;
      end;
```

Right now it's giving me an exception. When I `showmessage(imgstream.DataString)`  I get a weird `BM6~` string back.

[image]

After adding `imgstream.Position := 0;` before the `CopyFrom` now I get data back blank, no exception:

[image]

Comment: *it's giving me an exception* is only meaningful if you include information about the specific exception you're seeing. We can't see your screen from here. As the first step, my psychic debugging skills tell me that you should have a `imgstream.Position := 0;` before the `CopyFrom`.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! Adding that now it no longer has an exception, but now it comes back blank. Please check above for screenshot.

Comment: I can't see the screenshot (corporate proxy doesn't allow image sharing sites, which is one of the reasons to avoid using images). Again though, I'm guessing you need to rewind the `OutputStream` by setting it's position before you access it.

Comment: Exception is `EReadError, Stream Read Error`, I've reset position before `showmessage` but still empty. `OutputStream.Position := 0;`

Comment: `showmessage` comes up blank, trying to add the output to a TMemo component freezes the program with no errors: `memo1.Lines.LoadFromStream(OutputStream);`

Comment: flush or free the encoder so that all data is written to the outputstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TBase64EncodingStream` is not suitable for big binary conversion, I mean, it will be very slow, also `Image1.Picture.SaveToStream`, by default, will save the picture as Bitmap format, so it will be very big. Try using JPG format.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  imgstream, Outputstream: TStream;
  Encoder: TBase64EncodingStream;
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  I: Int64;
begin
  I := GetTickCount64;
  imgstream := TMemoryStream.Create();
  Outputstream := TStringStream.Create('');
  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  Encoder := TBase64EncodingStream.Create(Outputstream);
  try
    jpg.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
    jpg.CompressionQuality:=75;
    jpg.SaveToStream(imgstream);
    imgstream.Position:= 0;
    Encoder.CopyFrom(TStringStream(imgstream), imgstream.Size);
    Encoder.Flush;
    Memo1.Text:='data:image/jpg;base64,'+ TStringStream(Outputstream).DataString;
    ShowMessage('Created in '+IntToStr(GetTickCount64-I)+'ms');
  finally
    imgstream.Free;
    Encoder.Free;
    Outputstream.Free;
    jpg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

To improve encoding it, maybe you could try using threads separating the binary in chunks multiple of 3 to process each one and join the processed encoded chunks at the end.

e.g. Using 4 threads, hard encoded.

```pascal
{ TEncodeThread }

  TEncodeThread = class (TThread)
  private
    fForm: TForm1;
    fStream: TStream;
    fStatusText: String;
    procedure ShowStatus;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended:Boolean; const AForm: TForm1);
    procedure SetStream(const AStream: TStream);
  end;   

...
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  mul3: Int64;
  mod3: Int64;
  dif3: Int64;
  imgstream: TStringStream;
begin
  Steps:=0;
  Start:=GetTickCount64;
  imgstream := TStringStream.Create('');
  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    jpg.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
    jpg.CompressionQuality:=75;
    jpg.SaveToStream(imgstream);

    mul3 := imgstream.Size div 4;
    mod3 := mul3 mod 3;
    if mod3 <> 0 then
       mul3 := mul3 + 3 - mod3;
    dif3 := imgstream.Size - mul3*4;
    memo1.text := 'Total Size: '+ IntToStr(imgstream.size)
    + #13'Part1: '+IntToStr(mul3)
    + #13'Part2: '+IntToStr(mul3)
    + #13'Part3: '+IntToStr(mul3)
    + #13'Part4: '+IntToStr(mul3+dif3)
    + #13'Rest: '+IntToStr(dif3);

    Part1.Position:=0;
    Part2.Position:=0;
    Part3.Position:=0;
    Part4.Position:=0;
    imgstream.Position:=0;
    Part1.CopyFrom(imgstream,mul3);
    Part2.CopyFrom(imgstream,mul3);
    Part3.CopyFrom(imgstream,mul3);
    Part4.CopyFrom(imgstream,mul3+dif3);

    Thr1 := TEncodeThread.Create(True, Self);
    Thr2 := TEncodeThread.Create(True, Self);
    Thr3 := TEncodeThread.Create(True, Self);
    Thr4 := TEncodeThread.Create(True, Self);

    Thr1.SetStream(Part1);
    Thr1.Start;
    Thr2.SetStream(Part2);
    Thr2.Start;
    Thr3.SetStream(Part3);
    Thr3.Start;
    Thr4.SetStream(Part4);
    Thr4.Start;

  finally
    imgstream.Free;
    jpg.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TEncodeThread.Execute;
var
  Encoder: TBase64EncodingStream;
  buf: TStream;
begin

    buf := TStringStream.Create('');
    Encoder := TBase64EncodingStream.Create(buf);
    try
      fStream.Position:= 0;
      Encoder.CopyFrom(TStringStream(fStream), fStream.Size);
      Encoder.Flush;
      buf.Position:= 0;
      fForm.Out1.CopyFrom(TStringStream(buf), buf.Size);
      Inc(fForm.Steps);
      if fForm.Steps = 3 then
      begin
        fForm.Out1.Position:=0;
        fForm.Out2.Position:=0;
        fForm.Out3.Position:=0;
        fForm.Out4.Position:=0;
        fForm.Memo1.Text:='data:image/jpg;base64,'
        + TStringStream(fForm.Out1).DataString
        + TStringStream(fForm.Out2).DataString
        + TStringStream(fForm.Out3).DataString
        + TStringStream(fForm.Out4).DataString;
      end;


    finally
      Encoder.Free;
      buf.Free;
    end;


end;
```

**This demo, is not really optimized, neither correctly synchronized** (output maybe wrongly formed), though, as a starting point it could be of help. [zipped project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QGDAyFb_G4MNJH_hqpQ0E--XOyPFqwBb)